# path is not a module in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I tried to create a custom component in my angular 2 application. My application structure is as follows :
[image: Folder Structure]

dept.component.html :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector : 'dept-sel',
templateUrl : './deptCom.component.html'
})
export class DeptComponent
{
    title = 'app1';
}
```

app.module.ts :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {DeptComponent} from './Departments/dept.component'


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DeptComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Facing the compilation error as like module not found in the path as like below image :
[image: compile error]

Comment: deptCom.component.html should be `dept.component.html`

Comment: Your app component uses dept component? If yes try giving dept component before app component.

Comment: Upvote if the answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template code should be **`dept.component.html`**  in **`dept.component.ts`**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
selector : 'dept-sel',
templateUrl : './dept.component.html'
})
export class DeptComponent
{
    title = 'app1';
}
```